# Postfix cannot email to any domain except locally

Tags: postfix, smtp

I installed the GitLab omnibus package on ubuntu 1404 desktop on my virtual box. Networking is bridged so that my PC and my colleagues in the same office can visit my ubuntu-virtual box. GitLab is setup correctly and everyone can visit it using my ubuntu's IP address or hostname.

Problem came when I tried to send email from ubuntu. Postfix is the mail server installed with GitLab and it only works **locally**, which means I can only send test emails to users on ubuntu. Whenever I send email to my email address at office or external email, the log shows:

```
Oct 21 16:22:43 ls-VirtualBox postfix/pickup[1380]: DF0E332007: uid=997 from=<gitlab@sam-VirtualBox>
Oct 21 16:22:43 ls-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[3782]: DF0E332007: message-id=<56272123cf760_3b919eeac0351c@ls-VirtualBox.mail>
Oct 21 16:22:43 ls-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[1381]: DF0E332007: from=<gitlab@ls-VirtualBox>, size=2748, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 21 16:22:44 ls-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[3786]: DF0E332007: to=<ls@mycompany.com>, relay=mail.mycompany.com[202.83.91.136]:25, delay=0.13, delays=0.05/0/0.08/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mail.mycompany.com[202.83.91.136] while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

The postfix configure file is [here](https://gist.github.com/sandyleo26/2673a7bf0c3937ff4dd3#file-mail-cf). Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to telnet SMTP port on mail.mycompany.com? [ `telnet mail.mycompany.com 25` ] Do you get SMTP greeting message?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I tried, and I got this `Trying 202.83.91.136... Connected to mail.mycompany.com. Escape character is '^]'. Connection closed by foreign host.`

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution is to put some `relayhost` in you `postfix` config.
`relayhost` is usually smtp of you ISP. When you put `relayhost` in config all mail from your server will be routed to `relayhost`.

Comment: I try to use gmail as relayhost as described in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871196/gitlab-postfix-configuration-mail-not-sending/28376198#28376198) but no luck either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Give me log when you use gmail like relayhost.

Comment: Maybe is solution to setup stand alone mail server. Nice guide is [here](http://uname.pingveno.net/blog/index.php/post/2014/02/01/Configure-Postfix-as-STMP-standalone-single-domain-server-using-Unix-users-and-PAM-on-Debian) Also have nice guide [here](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-setup-simple-but-yet-powerful-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-and-sasl-in-debian-6-squeeze/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that smart host (mail relay) you use (`mail.mycompany.com`) rejects SMTP connections from your host.

Based on reject procedure it may reject them due to tcpwrappers configuration.

Comment: Do you mean I should try to test other mail address? Well, I'll do that on Monday. Is there commands or logs can be used to troubleshoot this issue?